# a perpendicular "object" to another "object" in a n-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry if I'm not too good at explaining and formatting(im new here :p)...

In a 2-dimensional space, if you have a line(1-dimensional) there is another line(1-dimensional) that is perpendicular to it. ***ax + by = 0*** => ***bx - ay = 0***

In a 3-dimensional space, if you have a line(1-dimensional) there is a plane(2-dimensional) that is perpendicular to it(and vice versa). ***ax = by = cz*** => ***bcx + acy + abz = 0***

I assume if there is a n-dimensional space, with an m-dimensional object, there would also potentially be an (n - m) dimensional object that is perpendicular to that object.

I want to know if

A. whether the assumption is true

B. and if it is, if its possible to find an general formula for it.

Comment: basically 
1. What you call an "object" is called a subspace
2. You need the theory of euclidian spaces to undestand what perpendicular means

Comment: But yes, you have the right intuition : in an euclidian space, the orthogonal of a m-dimensional subspace is a (n-m) dimensional subspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general concept is called [orthogonal complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement).

The orthogonal complement of a subspace $W$ of a vector space $V$ equipped with a bilinear form $B$ is the set $W^\perp$ of all vectors in $V$ that are orthogonal to every vector in $W$.

A usual case is an inner product space $V$ where the bilinear form $B$ is the inner product. The complement of the subspace $W$ is written as
$$
W^\perp=\{v\in V:\langle w,v\rangle=0 \ \textrm{for all } w\in W\}
$$

In your first example, $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $W=\{(x,y):ax+by=0\}$.